# Haxm - the system requirements are not satisfied

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-virtual-device, haxm

i have been trying to install haxm for last few days..vt in my boot menu is enabled.. i also runned

> dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype offdism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

on my command prompt after seeing on a yt video...still it isn't installing..when i tried to install manually it says ****system requirements are not satisfied****
[here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf02c.png)

and,when i run my emulator on android studio..it shows nothing but black screen

can anyone please give solution how i can install haxm on my device

[my pc specifications are given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgCoe.png)

Answer (score 2):

This only works on hp devices:
Restart your device. As it starts turning on, press the Esc key repeatedly until it opens a startup menu. Press f10 to open the Bios.

- Select System Configuration
- Select Virtualization Technology
- Use the arrow key to enable it.
- Then restart your device

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU does not support `EPT` but does support `VT-x`. A CPU that supports both should have these lines in it's specification:

```
Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x) Yes
Intel® VT-x with Extended Page Tables (EPT) Yes
```

[EPT is required by haxm](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Windows-Installation-Environment-Check-and-Configurations). Some older Intel CPU models support `VT-x` but do not support `EPT`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open cmd and run : bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
2. Disable hyper V  Disable
3. windows platform virtualiszation

and it should work